# AWS Redshift accepting duplicates , although Primary Key is declared

Tags: amazon-redshift

I'm new to Redshift. I need help in understanding this behavior of Redshift that I came across. So, I used the following Query to create a new table :

```
CREATE TABLE customer
  (
     cust_id         INTEGER NOT NULL UNIQUE,
     email           VARCHAR(30),
     name            CHAR(30),
     PRIMARY KEY     (cust_id)
  );
```

Now, the table is getting created successfully but when it comes to data insertion using the following query :

```
INSERT INTO customer VALUES (1, 'john.doe@email.com', 'John Doe')
```

The table is accepting duplicates even though the Primary key is defined. Can someone help understand this behavior ?

I'm also going through redshift documentation to understand the cause behind this.

Comment: [Quote from the manual](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_unsupported-postgresql-features.html) "*Unique, primary key, and foreign key constraints are permitted, but they are informational only*"  - another good example why Redshift questions should not be tagged with PostgreSQL

Comment: Thanks. I had read the documentataion.

Answer (score 5):

Redshift and most clustered warehouse databases don't enforce uniqueness constraints.  This is due to the prohibitive costs of checking uniqueness across a cluster.  For example Snowflake DB works exactly the same way.

Your ETL processes need to enforce uniqueness if you need to the values to be unique in Redshift.

From - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/t_Defining_constraints.html

> Uniqueness, primary key, and foreign key constraints are informational
> only; they are not enforced by Amazon Redshift. Nonetheless, primary
> keys and foreign keys are used as planning hints and they should be
> declared if your ETL process or some other process in your application
> enforces their integrity.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I had read the documentation.